# How to delete a function from the call stack and run it in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I want to create my custom readFile JS function. But, I don't want it to be a synchronous function because it's meant to be used for reading huge files, so this would prevent my program to move forward for a while. **I want it to run in parallel** with the rest of the program.

By wrapping the call to that function with a setTimeout(0) it would just wait the call stack to be empty and then I would run it, but I don't want it: I want it to run in parallel.

Would it be possible?

Comment: `readFile` is already async, but you likely want to use [`createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) for this. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @JohnnyHK ``async != parallelism``. The callback still have to wait for the execution stack to be empty to get called.

Comment: @mdziekon Not sure what you're specifically getting at, but calling `readFile` doesn't block while the file is read; the file I/O reading occurs outside of the main thread. So it's effectively parallel. The `readFile` callback would, of course, run in the main thread.

Comment: @JohnnyHK ``The readFile callback would, of course, run in the main thread.`` that's my point exactly. OP specifically said he wants to implement his own ``readFile`` function which is run in parallel entirely.

Comment: @mdziekon Could be. It's not clear to me from the question.

Comment: @JohnnyHK ``I want to create my custom readFile JS function. (...) I want it to run in parallel``. Pretty obvious to me.

Comment: I said readFile just as an example. Now I see it's not the best possible example because reading a file implies using the C++ API (so it effectively will run in parallel/in other thread different from the main one). My fault. I want to create a function that doesn't use any kind of C++ API or similar, and I want it to run in parallel with the main thread. Is it possible?

Comment: In that case, you should listen to @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to achieve parallelism by spawning separate processes that are run in parallel to the "parent" one. This is a "node-only" solution.

You could also try out WebWorkers, eg. using this implementation: [`webworker-threads`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads). WebWorkers should work both in the browser and Node.js.